# target= "_blank" doesn't work when I apply Google Analytics button tracking onclick gtag_report_conversion

Tags: html, google-analytics

target= "_blank" doesn't work when I apply Google Analytics button tracking onclick gtag_report_conversion

```
<a href="https://mylink" target="_blank"onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('https://mylink);">CLICK ME!</a>
```

But, If I use _gaLink(this), it will open a new window. Is this a code I can use?

```
<a href="https://mylink" target="_blank"onclick="return _gaLink(this);">CLICK ME!</a>
```